# Dropdown is staying on the screen when I hit breakpoints in JavaScript files. Why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer-8, breakpoints

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition SP1 & IE8. When I hit a breakpoint in a JavaScript file that's triggered when an item in a dropdown is selected the dev environment takes focus, but the dropdown list is still visible, hovering over the code. This makes it very unreadable! Does anyone have any idea what's causing this? Or how it can be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried updating your video drivers?

Comment: good question.. no, I'll talk to the sys admins about that! thanks

Comment: Updating the video drivers will not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pause IE in the Javascript debugger, the entire process is paused.

Therefore, it cannot handle Windows messages and hide the dropdown (which is a topmost borderless window).

You can solve this by running the code (and pausing IE) after the dropdown is closed.
To do that, you can wrap your code in `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 10);`.
Note that that may change the behavior of the code.

The best solution is to get a second monitor and put IE on one monitor and the debugger in the other monitor.

[**Every developer should have (at least) two monitors**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/06/multiple-monitors-and-productivity.html).

Comment: The problem is his dropdown box from the browser is still displaying on top of his Visual Studio IDE, it's a display bug.

Comment: It isn't a display bug.  The window containing the dropdown list has not been hidden.  You should be able to see the window in Spy++.

Comment: And +1 for "Every developer should have (at least) two monitors!

Comment: I just figured the IE window shouldn't be displaying on top of your Visual Studio IDE, but I'll take your word for it.  I never noticed this issue but I use 2 monitors.

Comment: +1 I'm going to send the link to the SysAdmins. We've been arguing for second monitors for a long time now, but the arguments are falling on deaf ears! Hopefully this will help convince them.